# processes in g++

Tags: c++, unix

can somebody please explain what exactly is going on when I do in my Unix

```
> g++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

and

```
> g++ hello.cpp
```

what is the difference? Only renaming from a.out to hello? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Only renaming. It is the purpose of the `-o` option.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is the only difference.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-output-file-option-79.